# Hitting route without refreshing session

Tags: php, laravel, session-cookies, polling, laravel-routing

I'm using Laravel 4 for building my one-page app and I need to implement a session timeout for the user to be redirected as soon as it is detected, I've been trying to check the $_SESSION/Session::exists() array through some polling requests but everytime I hit a route the session is refreshed.

How can I implement polling for session info on Laravel effectively? Do I need to do something more complicated like keeping an open connection (Websockets/Long pooling)?

I feel like this should be an out-of-the-box feature but strangely no-one seems to implement it, is it because most of the implementations are page-to-page instead of one-page + ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a funny problem and you should use a middleware for that. If you're in laravel 4.1 or above laravel uses [StackPHP](http://stackphp.com/)

Check this [link](http://fideloper.com/laravel-http-middleware) from fideloper, it might be useful.

Just set/update session variable(defined by you) in the middleware and create route that doesn't use the middleware in your API to query that variable.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not there in Laravel out of the box but it's actually easy to implement. Just an example: you could store the time the user logged in in a session variable with `Session::put('logintime', time());` and then check if there has been a timeout.

Example (with a 15 min timeout):

```
function isTimeout() {
    return !Session::has('logintime') || Session::get('logintime') + (15 * 60) <= time();
}
```

Then you can use it in a response to an AJAX request like you need to.

Comment: I think this doesn't solve my problem since I need to keep registering that time on every route the user takes (session refreshes on each request) and if I do that by using App::before then all the routes will update the timer and it will be the same problem again, creating a filter and putting it around all routes except the timeout route its out of question since it will make the creation of new routes a problem for new developers unfamiliar with our code.

Comment: Which Laravel version do you use? With Laravel 5 you can just use a Middleware

Comment: Currently using Laravel 4.2.17

Answer (score -1):

It might be a long shot due to knowledge boundaries for some, but I do below for real time data displays in my applications, and it's worth the effort of getting started with NodeJS (and it's easier than people think as full stack PHP developers are already familiar with JS, highly recommend going into MEAN stack)

I write core functionality in a PHP framework, and for anything that I need to display or interact the user with in real time, instead of polling or using php with websockets, I introduce an extra nodejs nginx server and serve the data using socket.io, which is good because it keeps connections to your db to a minimum (ie hence avoiding any max connection problems in Mysql) and is super scaleable, as instead of polling it uses observable pattern, keeping all client connections in an array and pushing the new data when observer sees changes in your data persistence layer, instead of keeping your server super busy with gazillions of naggy clients polling your db all the time.

If you haven't done it, I also recommend dropping apache for your PHP application servers and look into Nginx with php fpm